# Searching an array: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, undefined, typeerror

Beginner coder here, so forgive me, I've searched but can't find anything to help me with this basic issue.

I have grid in the form of arrays within an array called 'cells', populated with 1s and 0s, representing living and dead cells. For each place on the grid I want to search the 8 places that surround it. I execute this with for loops:

```
  
    
    //iterate through the whole board
    
    for (y = 0; y < cells.length; y++) {
      for (x = 0; x < cells[0].length; x++) {
        
        let liveNeighbours = 0;
        let deadNeighbours = 0;
        
        //iterate through neighbours in 9 cell grid, ignore the cell itself
        for (yy = y - 1; yy <= y + 1; yy++) {
          for (xx = x - 1; xx <= x + 1; xx++) {
              if (yy !== y || xx !== x) {
                
                if (typeof(cells[yy][xx]) !== 'undefined') {
                  if (cells[yy][xx] === 1) {
                    liveNeighbours++;
                  } else if (cells[yy][xx] === 0) {
                    deadNeighbours++;
                  }
                }

            }
          }
        }
        
        console.log('Looking at cell ' + x + ', ' + y);
        console.log('Live neighbours ' + liveNeighbours);
        console.log('Dead neighbours ' + deadNeighbours);        
        
        
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

This seems like the simplest method, although obviously it means that the search will occassionally be looking at undefined array indexes (cells[-1][-1]). I've tried to get around this by implementing a typeof check but I still receive the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined`

It refuses to check the typeof *because* it is undefined, even though that's exactly what I want to know. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you think of your top left item in the grid, it will not have a top left, top, top right, left, or bottom left neighbor. I think your code `cells[yy][xx]` at some point references a non-existent neighbor, most likely at the [yy] position. if `cells[yy]` does not exist, it is undefined, therefore trying to access `[xx]` on it is a property that is attempted to be accessed on undefined. So check that `cells[yy]` and `cells[yy][xx]` are not null or undefined before trying to use them. (checking for falsey will have a false positive depending on the contents)

Comment: Hi there, that was the purpose of my if (typeof(cells[yy][xx]) !== 'undefined') check. It still throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better way to do it:

```js
cells[yy]?.[xx]
```

Using the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator. Will return undefined if either `cells[yy]` or `cells[yy][xx]` is `undefined`.

That way you don't need that `if` wrapper at all because `undefined !== 1` and `undefined !== 0`.

Old code:

```js
if (typeof(cells[yy][xx]) !== 'undefined') {
    if (cells[yy][xx] === 1) {
        liveNeighbours++;
    } else if (cells[yy][xx] === 0) {
        deadNeighbours++;
    }
}
```

New code:

```
if (cells[yy]?.[xx] === 1) {
    liveNeighbours++;
} else if (cells[yy]?.[xx] === 0) {
    deadNeighbours++;
}
```

Edit: [CanIUse Optional Chaining Operator?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) (Yes, except for IE)

Comment: I didn't know optional chaining worked with subscripting like that.

Comment: Yeah I didn't either but felt like it had to exist and lo and behold it does. The more you know!

Comment: yeah, it just depends on whether your js environment supports it or not

Comment: if `cells[yy]` is null, it won't count as a deadNeighbour. you should probably check the inverse of `else if (cells[yy]?.[xx] !== 1)`, for which a `cells[yy]` null/undefined value OR a `cells[yy][xx]` value of `0` (non-1 value) would count as a dead neighbour. Is that the intended effect?

Comment: @ps2goat is it supposed to count as a dead neighbor? I don't know much about GOL but what I do know is that the code I provided has the same functionality as the old code (in the old code `liveNeighbours` and `deadNeighbours` are not touched outside of the check for `undefined`).

Comment: @MattF. it was more of a question for OP

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. The problem is that `typeof(cells[yy][xx]) !== "undefined"` will not work when `yy` is out of range, because it will try to access a subscript of `undefined`.

Change that to

```
if (typeof cells[yy] !== "undefined" && typeof cells[yy][xx] !== "undefined")
```